# Subdomain with subfolder gets a 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have multiple subdomains that are working with a redirect, but bad for SEO

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&:_-]+)/actions$ http://$1.actions.mydomain.nl [R=301,L]
```

I want to redirecting to:

```
http://$1.mydomain.nl/actions
```

but here i get a 404 error.

How to make the right rule for this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9&:_-]+)/actions$ http://$1.mydomain.nl/actions [R=301,L]
```

So the destination becomes `http://subdomain-name.mydomain.nl/actions`. So the first thing you need is to make sure a DNS entry is setup to point `subdomain-name.mydomain.nl` to the right IP address/server. Then on the actual server you need to make sure that the requests are routed to the right place. So assuming that the actual resource is `/subdomain-name/actions`, you'd need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^actions$ /%1/actions [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code i have:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9&:_-]+).actions.mydomain.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ file.php?seo_naam=%1 [L,QSA]

This is working,but multiple(2 level) subdomains are not a good thing for seo.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9&:_-]+).actions.mydomain.nl$ [NC]

but i want to change this to:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9&:_-]+).mydomain.nl\actions$ [NC]

does not work

the thing is that the file.php?seo_naam=%1 should be loaded otherwise it will not work.